# A symmetric matrix with nonzero principal minors is cogredient to a diagonal matrix via an upper triangular

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, determinants

A paper I'm reading in representation theory states the following result:

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero, and $x$ a symmetric matrix in $M_n(F)$ all of whose principal minors are not zero.  Then there exists an upper triangular unipotent matrix $u$ such that $ux \space ^tu$ is diagonal.

I am looking for a reference for this result, or a suggestion on how to think about this to be able to prove it myself.

With respect to the standard basis in $F^n$, symmetric matrices correspond to symmetric bilinear forms, with invertible matrices corresponding to nondegenerate forms.  I am trying to think about how to interpret the fact that the principal subdeterminants of $x$ are also nonzero, in terms of the symmetric form.

Comment: As far as I remember, this should bear the name `Jacobi's method'...

Comment: anyway, this is what happens in the method here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr  when Case I always applies.

Comment: hmmm From Horn and Johnson, it seems Jacobi's method is rather specific, conerging to eigenvalues on the diagonal......